# $.children() vs $.children('className') What's difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two class as below:
--- css:

```
.shw-intro {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgb(95, 190, 0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 50px;
}
.shw-intro-content {
    display: none;
}
```

--- html:

```
<div class="shw-intro">
    <div class="shw-intro-content">hello</div>
    <div class="shw-intro-content">everyone</div>
    <div class="shw-intro-content">have fun</div>
 </div>
```

In javascript I have tried make some animation but I surprised between two situations:

```
var currentShw = 0;
```

Situation 1:

```
 function shwAnimation() {
            if ($('.shw-intro').attr('class').indexOf('shw-intro-translate') != -1) {
                $('.shw-intro').removeClass('shw-intro-translate');
                currentShw = currentShw >= $('.shw-intro-content').length ? 0 : currentShw + 1;
            }
            else {
                $('.shw-intro').children().eq(currentShw).show(); // It works fine
                $('.shw-intro').addClass('shw-intro-translate');
            }
        }
```

Situation 2:

```
function shwAnimation() {
        if ($('.shw-intro').attr('class').indexOf('shw-intro-translate') != -1) {
            $('.shw-intro').removeClass('shw-intro-translate');
            currentShw = currentShw >= $('.shw-intro-content').length ? 0 : currentShw + 1;
        }
        else {
            $('.shw-intro').children('shw-intro-content').eq(currentShw).show(); // It doesn't work
            $('.shw-intro').addClass('shw-intro-translate');
        }
    }
```

Comment: The situation 2 doesn't work

Comment: `shw-intro-content` looks for elements whose tag name is `<shw-intro-content>`. You forgot to add the `.` in front of it to make it a class selector.

Comment: It's not `.children('className')` but rather `.children('selector')` and you could see http://api.jquery.com/children/ for more information. You can make it a class with `.children('.className')` or find an ID with `.children('#id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a string to [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), it filters the results based on that selector.

So

```
.children('.shw-intro-content')
```

would only return the children **that have that class**

That said, what you have

```
.children('shw-intro-content')
```

<strike>isn't really a valid selector</strike> is a selector that will match tags of type `shw-intro-content` which I assume don't exist, which is probably why it doesn't work; it will result in nothing being returned.

Did you forget the dot?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mr Adam Rackis! At the first time I try I think it's not really need a dot(.). But now I have just tried to add a dot(.) and it works fine for me. So let me ask you a question? What's going on if I use .children('shw-intro-content')? How does it work? What does it call? Thanks.

Comment: It works the same way any other jQuery selector works "X" means tags of type X, ".X" is a css class of X, and so on

Comment: Nit: `shw-intro-content` *is* a valid selector .. it just won't match as there are no elements with such a name. However, consider: `document.createElement("shw-intro-content")`.

Comment: True, I was making the assumption that you didn't have any tags of type `shw-intro-content` - as @user says though, if you do, your selector will match them

Answer (score 2):

You should use a CSS selector as a parameter for `.children()`.

Like this: `$('.shw-intro').children('.shw-intro-content')`

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
function shwAnimation() {
 if ($('.shw-intro').attr('class').indexOf('shw-intro-translate') != -1) {
     $('.shw-intro').removeClass('shw-intro-translate');
   currentShw = currentShw >= $('.shw-intro-content').length ? 0 : currentShw + 1;   }
    else {
        $('.shw-intro').children('.shw-intro-content').eq(currentShw).show(); 
        $('.shw-intro').addClass('shw-intro-translate');
    }
}
```

You have to use class selector by usng "."